# How to get stack range of kernel module? How to fflush printf or uprintf in FreeBSD?

Tags: stack, kernel, printf, freebsd, kernel-module

First, how to get the stack start and end address of a loaded kernel module in FreeBSD?

Second, how to get all the output of `uprintf` or `printf` or `iprintf` out? Usually when kernel panics, some print-out results are missing. Any way to ``fflush'' them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`stack(9)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=stack&sektion=9) to get a stack trace for a *kernel thread*. But *modules* themselves don't have an stack.

To be as sure as possible that you capture output, use `printf(9)` or `log(9)`. Those will log to syslog.

Comment: I mean the *stack* address, not the code/.text address.